# wso2 custom mediator inside carbon app

Tags: esb, wso2, mediator

I developed a custom mediator and its corresponding Factory/Serializer classes so that I can configure complex configuration options for it inside a sequence. This was made with a carbon app project using carbon studio.

The thing is that the only way I can make the configuration element to work is by deploying the jar file outside the **.car** file.

Can I just deploy the **.car** file to make it work? Where do I have to put the **META-INF/services** folder in order to work properly?

Here's my CarbonAppProject structure

```
CarbonApp
+--artifacts
   +--lib
   +--library
      +--bundle
         +--jXLS <-- Java Library Artifact
   +--synapse
      +--mediator
         +--XlsToObjectMediator <-- Custom Mediator Artifact
+--builder
+--META-INF
   +--services
      +--org.apache.synapse.config.xml.MediatorFactory <-- FILE
      +--org.apache.synapse.config.xml.MediatorSerializer <-- FILE
+--src
   +--main
      +--java
         +--<package> <-- mediator, factory and serializer clases
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: This carbon app I'm developing will have 2 mediators XlsToObject and ObjectToXls using jXLS library which I am willing to share with wso2 community!

Comment: I finally managed to find a workaround by creating a Mediator project containing the mediator classes, service folder inside META-INF and the external dependency JARs inside a lib folder at the root level. Then I generated the deployable JAR file which I deployed as an extension into [CARBON_HOME]\repository\deployment\server\extensions. I'm still tying to find out how to deploy all that inside a .car file though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get this to work with this version of Carbon Studio but it is possible to get it work with newer version of it. You can get the newer version from http://builder1.us1.wso2.org/~developerstudio/developer-studio/2.0.0/RC1/wso2-developer-studio_2.0.0.RC1.zip

Steps.

1. Create a ESB Custom mediator project and create your mediator sources there
2. Copy the META-INF/services folder to the src/main/resources folder of the same project.
3. Build the Custom Mediator project with Maven
4. Create a Java Library Artifact project and make sure to add jXLS library to it.
5. Build the Java Library Artifact Project with Maven
6. Create Carbon Application Project
7. Add the Custom Mediator Project and Java Library Artifact project as dependencies of the Carbon Application Project.
8. Build the C-App project with Maven

Now you will be able to get the ESB Custom Mediator running in ESB without any issue.

```
.
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    `-- main
        |-- java
        |   `-- ddd
        |       `-- dd.java
        `-- resources
            `-- META-INF
                `-- services
                    |-- org.apache.synapse.config.xml.MediatorFactory
                    `-- org.apache.synapse.config.xml.MediatorSerializer
```

Your mediator project structure would be similar to above

Hope this helps!!

Thankss.

/Harshana

Comment: Hi Harshana, please notice the amendments to my original post.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @nicolasdij I modified my answer according to the amendments you provided.. hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks Harshana. I created Mediator and Java Library projects separately but in order to compile the first one I need to add the jXLS jars to the build path. Is there a way to add a dependency from the Mediator to the Java Library project to achieve this?

Comment: Ni @nicolasdij, Please find the newly added comment to solve this issue. Hope this helps!!

Comment: Hi Harshana, although your answer is really useful and even after following your suggestions I managed to create a .car file with both the Java Library and Custom Mediator, I couldn't succeed in Carbon ESB finding the Factory class for the mediator. The only way I found is deploying the the Java Library and the Custom Mediator artifacts as separated JAR files. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: @nicolasdij, You should be having 3 artifacts, JavaLibArtifact and 2 custom mediators. There is a server side issue due to C-App deployer deploys the artifacts Async manner. So there is an opportunity that your Custom mediators gets deployed before deploying JavaLibraryArtifact which could cause the custom mediator deployment to fail. It is the only logical explanation at this point :-) To avoid that you have to have 2 C-Apps for Java Library artifacts and for custom mediators. Deploying Java library Artifact C-App before the custom mediator C-App should solve your issue.

Comment: Reason: When you want to implement a custom mediator with serializers and deserializers, you cannot use CAR file based approach. Reason is that, when you write a complete ESB custom mediator, you need to deploy to <ESB_HOME>/repository/components/extensions location. And the extension deployer takes care of some extra work apart from installing bundle in OSGi system. But when you use CAR approach, bundle get deployed and installed to the OSGi system. But those extra tasks performed by extension deployer are not performed. Thus your serializer classes are not available to the OSGi environment.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think declaring a project level dependency between JavaLibraryArtifact project and Custom mediator project will solve this.

But you can achieve this by adding the dependency to the actual 3rd Party Library from the mediator project.

Steps:

1. Right click on the Custom mediator project, select Build Path -> Configure Build Path
2. Go to Libraries Tab and Select "Add Jars" button. This will populate the Project Browser dialog
3. Expand the JavaLibraryArtifact Project in the Project Browser and select the jXLS library from the file list in there and click on "Ok"

Now you have added the jXLS to your Custom mediator project buildpath. So you won't see any errors in your Custom Mediator project.

If you open the .Classpath file of the Custom mediator project, you will see an entry similar to following.

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/JavaLibArtifactProject/jXLS.jar"/>
```

To avoid compilation errors from Maven, you need to add a Dependency to jXLS library in the Custom mediator project pom.xml.

By following the above steps you can avoid duplicating the JXLS library in your projects.

Hope this helps!!

Thanks.

/Harshana

Comment: Thanks Harshana, I solved the libraries dependency in Eclipse by taking your answer. The .car file is created successfully but when deployed in Carbon ESB, the mediator's services metadata is not loaded unless I deploy jXLSLibrary and XlsToObjectMediator JARs separately. Maybe there's something in the ESB server that's not working with custom mediators bundled inside a CarbonApp file.